# Generate unique usernames in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

How can I generate unique usernames based on a format. So for example the first user signs up. The username for him is AAA001 the second user signs up the username will be AAA002, and it keeps incrementing like that. How can I set it up so even if two users click sign up at the same time the database just sends them each a unique username. This is gonna be done on RoR.

Thank you in advance

Comment: BTW the last username will be ZZZ999 (Im just writing this for demo purpose to show that the letters increment too.)

Answer (score 0):

you can generate the username in the after_safe hook of the model and save! again in a transaction (to prevent race conditions) and use the DB-ID of the already saved user to generate the username

Comment: So I should save the user again, and apply the new user name? How do you know a way I could increment from the last user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use database transactions.

Here is an example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  #code goes here
end
```

This will ensure that the code inside the transaction is blocking.

Comment: So this will be in the model? How would I go about retrieving the user name and show it to the user